# Error while installing opencart-1.5.5.1

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to install `opencart-1.5.5.1` on my localhost. But i am getting an error after STEP3-CONFIGURATION. The error is

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '\'0\', `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', PRIMARY KEY
>   (`address_id`' at line 13 Error No: 1064

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_address` ( `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `company` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `company_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `tax_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `address_1` varchar(128) NOT NULL, `address_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL, `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL, `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL, `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`), KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci; in D:\wamp\www\vogue\system\database\mysql.php on line 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because probably You have `magic_quotes_gpc` directive turned `On`, thus all quotes and apostrophes gets escaped by auto adding of slashes...

In Your `php.ini` find the directive `magic_quotes_gpc` and set to **`Off`**.

Comment: i set both  `magic_quotes_runtime` & `magic_quotes_sybase` to `off` now its working thanks for your help..